# Parameter to Filter using 'AND', 'OR', or 'EQUAL' in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, filtering, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with employees' names (first, last), birthdate, SSN.  I have set parameters that will filter on each with LIKE to only select first 2 or 3 letters of the first/last names.  However, the user will not always have the exact spelling of the first or last name, so all instances are shown when the report is run (i.e., Montrose, Juan, Montana, Juanjita, etc.). (see below).  How can I set parameters to allow user to select from a drop-down box different scenarios or combinations of Employee _LAST_NAME   and Employee _FIRST_NAME using 'and' / 'or', 'equal' / 'or', to narrow the list of names returned when using 'LIKE'.  Is it possible to set up a stored procedure to obtain this feat?
Thank you All in advance for any input or suggestions.

```
----(
----declare @Employee_ID varchar(35)
----declare @Employee_BIRTH_DATE varchar(20)
----declare @Employee_LAST_NAME varchar(40)
----declare @Employee_FIRST_NAME varchar(40)
----set @Employee _ID =' '
----set @Employee_BIRTH_DATE = ‘ '
----set @Employee _LAST_NAME =' '
----set @Employee _FIRS`enter code here`T_NAME =' ')
----(Employee_LAST_NAME LIKE UPPER(@Employee_LAST_NAME) + '%') OR 
----(Employee_FIRST_NAME LIKE UPPER(@Employee_FIRST_NAME + '%')) OR 
----(Employee_STU_ID = @Employee_ID) OR (Employee_BIRTH_DATE = 
----@Employee_BIRTH_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create a data-driven parameter that calls a stored procedure.   You pass the firstName and lastName parameter to that stored procedure, and it employs whatever logic you desire to produce a list of name-combinations.  It will then show up as a drop-down list in your third parameter.

You can google SSRS Cascading Parameters for more detailed examples.